# Config::Simple, how to change default output header?

Tags: perl, config

Testing the generation on the fly of config files in `ini` format with the package [Config::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Config::Simple) generates the desired file but always with the same header section, which includes the name of the Perl package at the beginning of the file. Does `Config::Simple` have a method to modify this default printing? I would like to replace this name with a new one.  Is it possible with some feature in the package?

Here is a toy code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;

my $cfg = new Config::Simple(
        syntax => 'ini'
) or die Config::Simple->error();
$cfg->param("Program.mode", "ALL");
$cfg->param("Program.strategies", "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
$cfg->param("Data.name_specie", "Homo sapiens");
$cfg->write("test.cfg") or die $cfg->error();
```

The output:

```
; Config::Simple 4.58
; Mon Mar 16 12:33:55 2020

[Program]
strategies=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
mode=ALL

[Data]
name_specie=Homo sapiens
```

Just wanted to replace the `; Config::Simple 4.58` line.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Can't be disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Simple" modules often aren't simple because they make so many decisions for you. If you don't like those decisions, you are stuck. This particular module hasn't been updated in over a decade and has several architectural issues. If you want INI files, use a different module, such as [Config:: IniFiles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles), [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny), or [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI) which are maintained and flexible.

My first thought was to subclass and override the method that adds the header since it was hard-baked into one of the methods. This is onerous because the module uses a combination of "private" subroutines and package variables. I tend to try this first because I don't disturb the original package:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

use Config::Simple;

package Local::Config::Simple {
    use parent qw(Config::Simple);

    # generates a writable string
    sub as_string {
        my $self = shift;

        my $syntax = $self->{_SYNTAX} or die "'_SYNTAX' is not defined";
        my $sub_syntax = $self->{_SUB_SYNTAX} || '';
        my $currtime = localtime;
        my $STRING = undef;
        if ( $syntax eq 'ini' ) {
            while ( my ($block_name, $key_values) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                unless ( $sub_syntax eq 'simple-ini' ) {
                    $STRING .= sprintf("[%s]\n", $block_name);
                }
                while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$key_values} ) {
                    my $values = join (Config::Simple::WRITE_DELIM(), map { Config::Simple::quote_values($_) } @$value);
                    $STRING .= sprintf("%s=%s\n", $key, $values );
                }
                $STRING .= "\n";
            }
        } elsif ( $syntax eq 'http' ) {
            while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                my $values = join (Config::Simple::WRITE_DELIM(), map { Config::Simple::quote_values($_) } @$value);
                $STRING .= sprintf("%s: %s\n", $key, $values);
            }
        } elsif ( $syntax eq 'simple' ) {
            while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                my $values = join (Config::Simple::WRITE_DELIM(), map { Config::Simple::quote_values($_) } @$value);
                $STRING .= sprintf("%s %s\n", $key, $values);
            }
        }
        $STRING .= "\n";
        return $STRING;
    }
}

my $cfg = Local::Config::Simple->new(
        syntax => 'ini'
) or die Config::Simple->error();
$cfg->param("Program.mode", "ALL");
$cfg->param("Program.strategies", "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
$cfg->param("Data.name_specie", "Homo sapiens");
$cfg->write("file.ini") or die $cfg->error();
```

That works and gives the output:

```
[Data]
name_specie=Homo sapiens

[Program]
mode=ALL
strategies=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

However, it broke several OO ideas, so I find this approach unpleasant. I can do a little bit less work by fixing the original package by redefining the original subroutine. Then the package variables and subroutines still work. Load the original module first then add your redefinitions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

use Config::Simple;
no warnings 'redefine';

package Config::Simple {
    # generates a writable string
    sub as_string {
        my $self = shift;

        my $syntax = $self->{_SYNTAX} or die "'_SYNTAX' is not defined";
        my $sub_syntax = $self->{_SUB_SYNTAX} || '';
        my $currtime = localtime;
        my $STRING = undef;
        if ( $syntax eq 'ini' ) {
            while ( my ($block_name, $key_values) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                unless ( $sub_syntax eq 'simple-ini' ) {
                    $STRING .= sprintf("[%s]\n", $block_name);
                }
                while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$key_values} ) {
                    my $values = join (WRITE_DELIM, map { quote_values($_) } @$value);
                    $STRING .= sprintf("%s=%s\n", $key, $values );
                }
                $STRING .= "\n";
            }
        } elsif ( $syntax eq 'http' ) {
            while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                my $values = join (WRITE_DELIM, map { quote_values($_) } @$value);
                $STRING .= sprintf("%s: %s\n", $key, $values);
            }
        } elsif ( $syntax eq 'simple' ) {
            while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$self->{_DATA}} ) {
                my $values = join (WRITE_DELIM, map { quote_values($_) } @$value);
                $STRING .= sprintf("%s %s\n", $key, $values);
            }
        }
        $STRING .= "\n";
        return $STRING;
    }
}

my $cfg = Config::Simple->new(
        syntax => 'ini'
) or die Config::Simple->error();
$cfg->param("Program.mode", "ALL");
$cfg->param("Program.strategies", "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
$cfg->param("Data.name_specie", "Homo sapiens");
$cfg->write("file.ini") or die $cfg->error();
```

I write quite a bit about this in [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com) as a way to deal with legacy code.

---

As a side note, you asked if there was some method in the module. You could have simply looked at the source to see what was happening and what was available. You would have seen that the header was hard-coded into `as_string`.

Comment: That is really complete answer! It plenty resolves the question. I am going to modify it accordingly. Could it be suggested to the authors?  I find it very useful. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Consider also [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) and [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI) which are both very simple and make slightly different design decisions.